# How to Open Modal in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new in MVC5, I have taken this snippet of code from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_sm&stacked=h) and made changes according to my need but it is not showing modal on button click. Please guide where I am missing...

References in my Master View

Head

```
<!--Start Bootstrap-->
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/CustomBootStrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--End Bootstrap-->
<!--Start Scripts-->
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJavaScript.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<!--End Scripts-->
```

Body

```
<div class="panel">
<div class="panel-heading div-bgGreen div-textWhite text-center"><span style="font-weight:600;" class="text-center">Recent Activities</span></div>
<div class="panel-body">
    Panel Content
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade bootstrap" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>This is a small modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have given all the references but why it was not showing modal. When I use "Pavan Teja"'s :-) given code, it worked for me. Pavan Teja's code also have those references. please let me know what is the reason behind this.
Regards

Comment: there is no flaw in this markup.. can you please share whole markup? before just check if your html contains any other element with `id=myModal`

Comment: have you include bootstrap.js in you file?

Comment: now I have provided whole mark-up, please review it

Comment: check the edited answer and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to include jquery and bootstrap.js to make it work.markup you provided is correct.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bootstrap" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is a small modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you have multiple jquery and bootstrap.js files included in file.you just need one refrence.change it to this.and bootstrap.js shoulb be after jquery.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJavaScript.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Accepted :-) Regards

Comment: sorry..i didnt see any points.can you check again.u accepted or upvoted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104782/discussion-between-wasif-and-pavan-teja).